Ubuntu 24.04 - Mouse cursor changes to hand w/finger point
I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a laptop with a trackpad, but I have mouse, keyboard and monitors connected via docking station.  I was typing and a gecko (small reptile) crossed the trackpad disrupting input and now mouse cursor is showing some very odd behavior.
On the laptop screen, it behaves normally, arrow cursor or input cursor when over text, and I get window resize handle cursors when hovering over resize handles on windows.
On my other screens, it will start off as the arrow cursor but if I hover over any text or clickable element (in a browser, Visual Studio Code, LibreOffice, etc) it changes to the hand with pointing finger.  From that point I cannot grab a window resize handle, and clicking on items is problematic because the click target is not where I expect at the end of the fingertip.
Mouse/keyboard settings do not appear to have any cursor behavior settings that I can see.  I saw a post recommending to change some kind of terminal mode via ctrl+alt+F1 - F7 but did not see any differences.
